# Is it possible a cancer cell don't express any foreign antigens?

Tags: genetics, immunology, cancer

For example, there're tumor suppressor genes. Can we just delete them, without introducing neo-antigens? Would the resultant cells proliferate? If so, how do our immune system identify such cells?

Comment: This question is far too broad, as explaining the mechanism of immune surveillance and how it applies to cancer is *much* too large of a subject to explain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many tumor suppressor genes have that function because they prevent mutations, repair DNA or kill the cell if it is "too far gone." If you knockout these genes, you will inevitably get mutations. As the cancer grows, there is a selective pressure which will favor cells that have beneficial mutations, likely in coding regions. These mutations will lead to the production of neo-antigens, which can be recognized by the immune system.

So, basically, I don't think it's likely that there would be a cancer without any neo-antigens whatsoever. That doesn't mean, however, that the immune system will adequately respond to the neo-antigens.